# Developers' Social Networking

Tags: social-networking

I am new here, and interested in collaboration and social networking sites. I wonder if any of the available social networks falls down under the "Developers' Social Networks" umbrella, if there are any.
And what makes us believe that they are developer's SNs ? How do developers use them?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, actually what brought me to SO is Scott's Hanselman article

Answer (score 4):

I would consider [github](http://github.com/) the ultimate social network for developers (... though you can fork me even if you don't know me).

Stackoverflow could be considered a developers social network as well. We unwittingly group ourselves under the tags we answer questions under and ask questions under, and a very visible heirarchy emerges thanks to the the karma system.

Yep... Stackoverflow is a socialnetwork, and [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is /root .

Answer (score 2):

What about

**[OpenSocial](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/)**

> Open Social is Google’s new collection
>   of application programme interfaces
>   (APIs). APIs are used to develop
>   nearly all social network sites. At
>   OpenSocial you can browse the
>   application gallery and get started
>   creating or modifying your own APIs.

**[SNetBase.com](http://www.snetbase.com/)**

> It provides a forum for professionals
>   involved in all aspects of programming
>   and Web development to share ideas,
>   tips, and resources.

**[Facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com/)**

> As a programmer, you can contribute to
>   the site by submitting idea or code
>   for an application or widget.

and read an article by Scott Hanselman

[Social Networking for Developers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SocialNetworkingForDevelopersConferenceTalkVideo.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My opinions are a bit different. They are not social networking sites but I suggest that a developer should play more on these sites than Orkut, Facebook etc. I don't think there can be one single option for this answer. If you are a die hard developer then you have lots of choices.

1. **Stack Overflow** (Obviously)
   It has all the features of a social networking site (most importantly, it is almost addictive).
2. **[CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com)**
   I consider it a platform for developer collaboration. Most important aspect of CodePlex (and Sourceforge) is that they have very little noise.
3. **[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/)**
   I love its **[lounge](http://www.codeproject.com/Lounge.aspx)**.

Note: I visit Facebook and Orkut just to see what they are doing technically because they are almost masterpieces of work. I can get a lot of ideas and inspiration from these sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think the social networking features of stack overflow are fantastic.

However, while stackoverflow is great for getting answers to highly specific questions, there is still a lot of really useful information on the web in the form of blogs. Often these blog posts are more general in nature and will answer questions you will have needed to ask in the future but will never have to. (a kind of prevention vs cure)

The comments people add to blog posts often add much value. I've noticed some tech/developer blogs with 'post comment using facebook profile' features. This feature is good in that you would be using the same username for every blog that you post a comment to. It also means all of your blog comments all over the web can be aggregrated to a single place (facebook). However, I would be very hestitant in using my facebook profile to post a comment on a public blog because I wouldn't want my tech comments being posted in my friends news feed as they would be completely irrelevant to 95% of my friends (and people might think I'm a total bore!)

Ideally there would be a version of facebook that is purely for developers. It would have a a feature similar to 'facebook connect' and every tech blog would implement this 'facebook connect' feature.

I'm sorry i've gone against the grain of stackoverlow and not actually answered the question that was posted. But the overall problem is highlighted in that I'm not sure where the best place is for this kind of discussion.